# Can we use the agora for live stream in the .net web application or not?

Tags: .net, blazor-server-side, live-streaming, agora-web-sdk-ng

How can I connect the agora live stream to the .net web application,
also, I have to record the streaming video and store it in storage.

Comment: Please Don't Write With Upper Case Letters Like This. It Is Very Annoying To Read Text Like That (+ that's not even how you write English)

Comment: If your question doesn't include any code (hence you didn't even try to implement it by yourself) you might want to ask that question on a different, more suitable platform.

Comment: @Bin4ry I don't have any idea how to integrate the agora with the .net web application, if you have any reference kindly reply

Comment: Ask on StackExchange